How can I make the Logstash output execute only once?
How can I make the Logstash output execute only once despite multiple heartbeat requests repeatedly indicating that an application is down?
I would like to ensure that the application being down only triggers the action I have set in the output once, and that it is reset if it goes back UP.
I tried a method using the UUID as a discriminator and then the timestamp, but nothing conclusive for me.
